# problem in finding the data

Tags: java, jdbc

while i am finding the data the field of `TelephoneNo` showing the result in float like 54435435.0.even when i inserted this phone no as 54435435 my code is

```
 String findby =cbfind.getSelectedItem().toString();
           if(findby.equals("")){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," SELECT EITHER REGISTRATION NO OR NAME");
 return;
        }

           if(findby.equals("RegNo"))
           {
           int regno1= Integer.parseInt(cbregn.getSelectedItem().toString());

            try
            {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            System.out.println("\n Driver loaded");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:wanisamajDB");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM REGISTRATION1 WHERE RegistrationNo="+regno1);
            System.out.println("Hi");
            rs.next();
            String per = rs.getString("SeniorPerson");
            System.out.println("SeniorPerson: " + per );
            String reg = rs.getString("RegistrationNo");
            System.out.println("RegistrationNo: " + reg);
            String nplace = rs.getString("NativePlace");
            System.out.println("NativePlace: " + nplace);
            String kul = rs.getString("Kul");
            System.out.println("Kul: " + kul);
            String gtr = rs.getString("Gotra");
            System.out.println("Gotra: " + gtr);
            String ksami = rs.getString("KulSwami");
            System.out.println("KulSwami: " + ksami);
            String raddr = rs.getString("ResidensialAddress");
            System.out.println("ResidensialAddress: " + raddr);
            String code = rs.getString("PinCode");
            System.out.println("PinCode: " + code);
            String stdcd = rs.getString("STDcode");
            System.out.println("STDcode: " + stdcd);
            String teleno = rs.getString("TelephoneNo");
            System.out.println("TelephoneNo: " + teleno);
            String mno = rs.getString("MobileNo");
            System.out.println("MobileNo: " + mno);
            String email = rs.getString("Email");
            System.out.println("Email: " + email);
            String web = rs.getString("Website");
            System.out.println("Website: " + web);
            String educ = rs.getString("Education");
            System.out.println("Education: " + educ);
            String brch = rs.getString("Branch");
            System.out.println("Branch: " + brch);
            String bgrp = rs.getString("BloodGroup");
            System.out.println("BloodGroup: " + bgrp);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "RECORD FOUND");

            cbnm.setSelectedItem(per);
            tfplace.setText(nplace);
            tfkul.setText(kul);
            tfgotra.setText(gtr);
            tfswami.setText(ksami);
            taraddr.setText(raddr);
            tfpcd.setText(code);
            tfstdcode.setText(stdcd);
            tftele.setText(teleno);
            tfmno.setText(mno);
            tfemail.setText(email);
            tfweb.setText(web);
            tfedu.setText(educ);
            tfbrch.setText(brch);
            cbbldgrp.setSelectedItem(bgrp);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION " + e);
            }
         }



           if(findby.equals("Name"))
           {
            try
            {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            System.out.println("\n Driver loaded");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:wanisamajDB");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM REGISTRATION1 WHERE SeniorPerson='"+cbnm.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'");
            System.out.println("Hi");
            rs.next();
            String per = rs.getString("SeniorPerson");
            System.out.println("SeniorPerson: " + per );
            String reg = rs.getString("RegistrationNo");
            System.out.println("RegistrationNo: " + reg);
            String nplace = rs.getString("NativePlace");
            System.out.println("NativePlace: " + nplace);
            String kul = rs.getString("Kul");
            System.out.println("Kul: " + kul);
            String gtr = rs.getString("Gotra");
            System.out.println("Gotra: " + gtr);
            String ksami = rs.getString("KulSwami");
            System.out.println("KulSwami: " + ksami);
            String raddr = rs.getString("ResidensialAddress");
            System.out.println("ResidensialAddress: " + raddr);
            String code = rs.getString("PinCode");
            System.out.println("PinCode: " + code);
            String stdcd = rs.getString("STDcode");
            System.out.println("STDcode: " + stdcd);
            String teleno = rs.getString("TelephoneNo");
            System.out.println("TelephoneNo: " + teleno);
            String mno = rs.getString("MobileNo");
            System.out.println("MobileNo: " + mno);
            String email = rs.getString("Email");
            System.out.println("Email: " + email);
            String web = rs.getString("Website");
            System.out.println("Website: " + web);
            String educ = rs.getString("Education");
            System.out.println("Education: " + educ);
            String brch = rs.getString("Branch");
            System.out.println("Branch: " + brch);
            String bgrp = rs.getString("BloodGroup");
            System.out.println("BloodGroup: " + bgrp);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "RECORD FOUND");

            cbregn.setSelectedItem(reg);
            tfplace.setText(nplace);
            tfkul.setText(kul);
            tfgotra.setText(gtr);
            tfswami.setText(ksami);
            taraddr.setText(raddr);
            tfpcd.setText(code);
            tfstdcode.setText(stdcd);
            tftele.setText(teleno);
            tfmno.setText(mno);
            tfemail.setText(email);
            tfweb.setText(web);
            tfedu.setText(educ);
            tfbrch.setText(brch);
            cbbldgrp.setSelectedItem(bgrp);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION " + e);
           }
       }//if
```

Comment: Is your db column for age set up as a varchar or as a number?

Comment: why cannt you make it as long int

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to wager that it's because that's how it's stored in the DB.

Use `varchar` rather than whatever it is you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are seeing is most likely due to:

- defining the column type for the telephone number to be "float", "double", "decimal", "numeric" or "real", or
- defining the column type as "char", "varchar", etc and populating it from a Java `float`, `double` or `BigDecimal`.

In either case, what you are seeing reflects the data stored in the database.